# issue in multi open accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have used multi open accordion for my web page. I have downloaded the script from this url http://anasnakawa.wordpress.com/2011/01/25/jquery-ui-multi-open-accordion/

It displays the tabs with first one in open state default. If i click the second section the first opened section should close and only the second one will open. How can i do it with multi open accordion?

The internal script is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('#multiOpenAccordion').multiOpenAccordion({
                active: [1, 2],
                click: function(event, ui) {
                    //console.log('clicked')
                },
                init: function(event, ui) {
                    //console.log('whoooooha')
                },
                tabShown: function(event, ui) {
                    //console.log('shown')
                },
                tabHidden: function(event, ui) {
                    //console.log('hidden')
                }

            });

            $('#multiOpenAccordion').multiOpenAccordion("option", "active", [0]);
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the below code in place of the one you have used.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#multiOpenAccordion').multiOpenAccordion({
        active: 1,
        click: function(event, ui) {
            //console.log('clicked')
            $("h3.ui-state-active").removeClass('ui-state-active').addClass('ui-state-default');
            $("div.ui-accordion-content-active").removeClass('ui-accordion-content-active').hide();
            $("h3.ui-accordion-header").addClass('ui-corner-all');  
        },
        init: function(event, ui) {
            //console.log('whoooooha')
        },
        tabShown: function(event, ui) {
            //console.log('shown')
        },
        tabHidden: function(event, ui) {
            //console.log('hidden')
        }

    });

    $('#multiOpenAccordion').multiOpenAccordion("option", "active", [0]);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi.. is there any other event for multiOpenAccordion plugin such as click? or if need to include new event what are the procedures? thanks